# Data from 3 related tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables. `table1` `table2` `table3`. `table1` is related `table2` with one to many relation. Also `table2` is related `table3` with one to many relation.

I need to get data from these tables with some columns of `table1`.

I tried follwing code.

```
$rece =  \App\Table3::with('table2','table2.table1')
                    ->get();
```

I am getting the complete json array in `$rece`. But i need to filter with some value of a column in `table1`. I tried

```
$rece =  \App\Table3::with('table2','table2.table1')
                    ->where('columnintable1', 'value')->get();
```

But its throwing error.

Comment: You can use Eloquent ORM relationships in this case.

Comment: i tried $rece->table2->table3->columnintable3. But it throws error that table2 method doesnt exist.

Comment: because you are doing in a wrong way..

Comment: I can give you complete solution if you tell your model names, and table structures.

Comment: alternate way: `$data = DB::table('table1')
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.primarykey', '=', 'table2.forenkey')
    ->leftJoin('table3', 'table2.primarykey', '=', 'table3.forenkey')
    ->where('columnintable3', 'value')
    ->get();` using DB Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$rece =  \App\Table1::with('table2','table2.table3')
                ->whereHas('table2.table3', function($query){
                    $query->where("columnname","value");
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\App\Table1::with(['table2', 'table2.table3' => function ($query) use ($variable) {$query->where('columnintable3', $variable);}])->get();
```

Comment: This works. Great. One more thing. How can i pass a variable to function for 'value'

Comment: `function ($query) use ($variable) {$query->where('columnintable3', $variable);}`

Comment: This solution returns all rows from table1. I need only ones which belongs to table2 & table3 with given conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Constraing eager loading:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
$rece =  \App\Table1::with(['table2','table2.table3'=>function($query) {
                     ->where('columnintable3', 'value');
                 }])->get();
```